# How can I insert variable database name in recorded Excel-VBA code?

Tags: sql, vba, excel

The code below is from a recorded macro in Excel 2016 during importing data from an SQL Server Express database.

```
Sub Macro2()

    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Query1", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Sql.Database(""DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS"", ""2014-All-1"", [Query=""SELECT *#(lf)  FROM [2014-All-1].[dbo].[OtherData]#(lf)#(lf)  WHERE volume > 1""])" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source"
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Query1" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Query1]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Query1"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End Sub
```

I have tried to make the database name variable, by adding variable `MyDB`, which is used twice in the long line of code as you can see. Originally this was the name of the database: 2014-All-1

Unfortunately this method does not work. Does someone know how I can replace the database with a variable name?

```
Sub Macro2()

MyDB = "2014-All-1"

    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Query1", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Sql.Database(""DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS"", ""MyDB"", [Query=""SELECT *#(lf)  FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[OtherData]#(lf)#(lf) WHERE volume > 1 ""])" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source"
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Query1" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Query1]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Query1"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd approach it:

```
Sub MyMacro()

Dim strMyDB as String
MyDB = "2014-All-1"

Dim strFormulaTemplate as String
strFormulaTemplate = "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Sql.Database(""DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS"", ""@@DBName@@"", [Query=""SELECT *#(lf)  FROM [@@DBName@@].[dbo].[OtherData]#(lf)#(lf)  WHERE volume > 1""])" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source"

Dim strFormula as String
strFormula = replace(strFormulaTemplate,"@@DBName@@",strMyDB)

ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Query1", Formula:= strFormula
...

End Sub
```

If you wanted, you could pass the database name as a parameter as follows:

```
Sub MyMacro(strMyDB as String)
...
```

Then call the Macro using `MyMacro("MyDB")`

Comment: Hello Steve, Thanks a lot for this elegant nice structered part of code! It works perfect! Best regards, Marcel

Comment: No worries, glad to have helped. I hate all that fiddling around with quote marks, so when this kind of thing comes up, I often use `Replace` for it rather than trying to build the string using concatenation. I think it tends to be easier to read too.

Comment: Yes, I will keep this in mind the for the next time I have a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify ""MyDB"" by : Chr(34) & MyDB & Chr(34), like :

```
 "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Sql.Database(""DESKTOP\SQLEXPRESS"", " & Chr(34) & MyDB & Chr(34) & ", [Query=""SELECT *#(lf)  FROM [" & Chr(34) & MyDB & Chr(34) & "].[dbo].[OtherData]#(lf)#(lf) WHERE volume > 1 ""])" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source"
```

Comment: Thanks, although this gives a Compile error: Expected named parameter.

Comment: Thanks, although this gives a Compile error: Expected named parameter.

Comment: To match the original code, change `FROM [" & Chr(34) & MyDB & Chr(34) & "]` to be `FROM [" & MyDB & "]`.  (The generated string won't need double-quotation marks while it is inside [brackets].)

Comment: Thanks Yow, although this gives the same Compile error: Expected named parameter.

Comment: My goal is to run several different queries on multiple databases. Alternatively I could copy the code multiple times and add a variabele to replace the part with the query. Although also this does not succeed.